# A arrow hover effect that's centered to the nav link boxes

Tags: php, html, css

I have a site I built in Wordpress that has a gray boxes around the links that when you hover over them they turn blue and an arrow drops down from the box. My problem is they are placed absolutely so if the Nav link is longer or shorter the arrow isn't centered to nav box. I was able to achieve the effect with pure CSS. Here is my code.

HTML

```
<div id="nav">

            <div class="navwrapper">
                    <div class="main-nav">
                        <?php bones_main_nav(); // Adjust using Menus in Wordpress Admin ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.main-nav ul a{
    color: #0f0f0f;
    text-decoration: none;
}


.main-nav ul li a{
    color: #0f0f0f;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #efefef;
    padding:  10px;
}


.main-nav ul a:hover{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #5dbbe0;
     -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
}


.main-nav ul li {
    float: left;
    margin:  25px 0 0 15px;
}


.main-nav ul a:hover:after{  
    content: ' ';  
    position: absolute;  
    width: 0;  
    height: 0;  
    left: 18px;  
    top: 36px;
    text-align: center;
    border-width:10px 10px 0;
    border-style: solid;  
    border-color: #5dbbe0 transparent;  
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: How do I get the arrows on their hover states to center with the nav boxes? Since my nav links(Home, About, Blog, FAQ, Services, Portfolio) our varying in widths the arrow moves according to how they are positioned. I want them to be centered to my links when you hover over them. 

Sorry if I didn't make that clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the issues with your current use of triangles is that your nesting **block elements** within **inline elements** which is invalid CSS. (You can nest inline elements within block elements though)

Since we  must use **display: block**; in order to form the CSS3 triangle, lets also add **display:block** to parent elements.

I also changed the position of the the triangle to **position:relative** because I wanted to position it relative to the anchor element

Finally use **margin:0 auto;** to horizontally align the triangle. I'm assuming that you are using the same height for each anchor, given that this is your navigation, so finally adjust the vertical position of the triangle accordingly using **bottom:-20px** for example

See demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/radialglo/Am48P/7/

I changed your **a:hover:after** to **a:after** just for demonstration purposes.

```
    .main-nav ul a{
        color: #0f0f0f;
        text-decoration: none;
    }


    .main-nav ul li a{
        color: #0f0f0f;
        text-decoration: none;
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background-color: #efefef;
        padding:  10px;
        display: block;
    }


    .main-nav ul a:hover{
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: #5dbbe0;
         -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        position: relative;
    }


    .main-nav ul li {
        float: left;
        margin:  25px 0 0 15px; 
        list-style: none;
    }


    .main-nav ul a:after {  
        content: ' ';  
        /* position: absolute; */
        position: relative;
        bottom: -20px;
        /*adjust vertical height as necessary */
        width: 0;  
        height: 0;  
        /* left: 18px;*/  
        /*top: 36px;*/
        text-align: center;
        border-width:10px 10px 0;
        border-style: solid;  
        border-color: #5dbbe0 transparent;  
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: block;
    }​
```

Comment: Your welcome! If you feel like I answered your question sufficiently, please click on the check mark next to my answer. Doing so confirms that your question has been resolved and also gives reputation points to both yourself and the user who answered your question, which not only enables more capabilities on stackoverflow, but also helps the users gain trust from peers. Thanks!